# SQL error ORA-00933 when performing a basic command

Tags: sql, select

Just started learning about SQL, and doing very basic stuff using SQLPlus.

I've literally just started and searching all over the web I can't seem to find any answers.

I have some pre made tables and I need to extract information from them using SELECT.

My code is below but every time I get

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

My code is as follows below. Please could you advise on where I'm going wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE wage > 20000 && < 350000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE wage>20000 AND wage<350000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative shorthand using `BETWEEN`, but functionally, identical.

```
SELECT * 
FROM staff 
WHERE wage BETWEEN 20000 AND 350000;
```

Comment: Excellent that worked perfectly thank you! Was '>' and '<' not the correct syntax then?

Comment: Actually ">" and "<" will work fine.  It was the "&&" that needed to be "AND" :-)  I just prefer between for these types of operations.  Glad it worked! Please accept answer.